# GRANT ALL needs additional privileges to alter or drop stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Hello everybody.

I am using MariaDB 10.0.24 on Windows 7.

I made a user using this command.

```
GRANT ALL ON target_DB.* TO `user_name`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY 'user_pass';
```

This works fine. But when the user 'user_name' tries to alter or drop stored procedures, below error is occurred.

> Unable to retrieve information. Please check your privileges. For
>   routines (stored procedures and functions) you need SELECT privilege
>   to mysql.proc if you are not the owner of the routines.

After googling, I found this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines-privileges.html

My questions are...

1. 'GRANT ALL' does not cover privileges for the stored routines?
2. If above answer is yes, what should I do for the 'user_name' to alter or drop stored routines?

Comment: Connect as `user_name`, then do `SHOW GRANTS;`  This _might_ give you a clue.

Comment: ... and while you are at that, try to alter a procedure directly from a command-line client, and if it fails, capture the real error message. What you have quoted is not produced by MariaDB server, it is an interpretaton by a 3rd-party software (webyog/sqlyog, apparently?) of whatever problem was encountered.